# Should I change a question title once I know the answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions

Look at [Why are empty and non empty TikZ matrix cells not equally placed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78964/1952). When I wrote it I didn't know the answer so its title was too general. Now, and because I think it's not so easy to find questions/answers in TeX.SX even I know I've read them, I think this general title is not so informative and I'm considering to change it with something like `why are empty and not empty cell in TikZ matrices missplaced?`or whatever you like.

Now my question is not only related whit this particular title but more general. Is it good to change question titles to make them more accurate with their answers?

Comment: IMHO yes. A title that better describes the issue will easier be found by others with similar problems which means that the question can be of more help to others.

Comment: Also under the condition the `edit` does not break the front line scroll Queue too often. Somewhat Related to `Q` Titles [Limiting the Length of Subject Titles](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3128/15717)

Comment: One thing to beware of is that you should make sure the question title is still informative to someone who does not know the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Check these questions (and their answers):

- [Changing the title of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152252/176533),
- [modify incorrect title based on answers [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181590/176533)
- [Should question titles be adjusted to actual cause of a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146975/176533)

The answer is: *Not really, but there is more to it.* Now, improving your title is great, you should do that, but not make it too based on the answers. Improve the title by itself and for itself, because whoever gets to your same problem will not know about the solution and will use *what they know* to search for the answer on Google. So by titling your question using the answers you're not helping who needs a solution. You should edit taking that into account.

If the title is too general it's not going to help either, so I agree that it would need editing as well, but make it independent.

On a related note, avoid tagging your question after it has been answered according to the answers. The tags are meant to categorize your question, not the answers.

In conclusion: Tag and title your question independently from its answers. If the title needs improvement, then feel free to edit and improve, that's what the edit button is for, but don't base it on the answers.